# setState alternative for abstract class?

Tags: flutter, dart, openstreetmap, markers, fluttermap

I want my map to update every time a new marker is added to it. I want to add some abstraction to my app, so I decided to dedicate the marker management to a MarkerManager class. Problem is, I now don't have the possibility to use setState, which I used for updating earlier. The markers appear when the map cursor is moved, though. Is there a way to update my screen without using setState? Here is my MarkerManager class :

```
class MarkerManager {

  void addSimpleMarker(LatLng latlng) {
    markers.add(
        simpleMarker(latlng)
    );
  }

  Marker simpleMarker(LatLng latlng) {
    return Marker(
        width: 40.0, height: 40.0,
        point: latlng,
        builder: (ctx) => FlutterLogo()
    );
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use some state manager like [Provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) or [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts)